# How to perform a SELECT by adding two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a table called `Person` with columns `name, surname and age.`

I want to add two  columns when performing a SELECT statment, probably something like this:

```
SELECT a FROM Person a WHERE a.name + a.surname LIKE ...
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not add string values, like names.  Presumably, you want to concatenate them, so you use the `concat()` function:

```
where concat(a.name, a.surname) like . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a FROM Person a WHERE CONCAT(a.name, a.surname) LIKE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

|| is the standard concat operator:

```
SELECT a FROM Person a WHERE a.name || a.surname LIKE ...
```

Note that you must have PIPES_AS_CONCAT set for that to work. As others have mentioned there is also a concat function that can be used.